# How to select top N rows for each group in a Entity Framework GroupBy with EF 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, group-by, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I need to get top 10 rows for each group in a table with entity framework.
Based on other solution on SO, I tried 2 things:

```
var sendDocuments = await context.Set<DbDocument>
    .Where(t => partnerIds.Contains(t.SenderId))
    .GroupBy(t => t.SenderId)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        t.Key,
        Documents = t.OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.InsertedDateTime).Take(10)
    })                
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression
'(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: (d.SenderId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: DbDocument
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False ) )
    .OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.InsertedDateTime)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync().
```

and

```
var sendDocuments2 = await context.Set<DbDocument>
    .Where(t => partnerIds.Contains(t.SenderId))
    .GroupBy(t => t.SenderId)
    .SelectMany(t => t.OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.InsertedDateTime).Take(10))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression
>   't => t
>       .OrderByDescending(t2 => t2.InsertedDateTime)
>       .AsQueryable()
>       .Take(10)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Any other idea?

Comment: can you provide what you want to do with an sql query? or can you provide the table structure?

Comment: context.Set<DbDocument>.FromSqlRaw amd write  group by query in that

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 6.0):**

EF Core 6.0 added support for translating `GroupBy` result set projection, so the original code for taking (key, items) now works as it should, i.e.

```cs
var query = context.Set<DbDocument>()
    .Where(e => partnerIds.Contains(e.SenderId))
    .GroupBy(e => e.SenderId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Documents = g.OrderByDescending(e => e.InsertedDateTime).Take(10)
    });
```

However flattening (via `SelectMany`) is still unsupported, so you have to use the below workaround if you need such query shape.

**Original (EF Core 3.0/3.1/5.0):**

This is a common problem, unfortunately not supported by EF Core 3.0/3.1/5.0 query translator specifically for `GroupBy`.

The workaround is to do the groping manually by correlating 2 subqueries - one for keys and one for corresponding data.

Applying it to your examples would be something like this.

If you need (key, items) pairs:

```
var query = context.Set<DbDocument>()
    .Where(t => partnerIds.Contains(t.SenderId))
    .Select(t => t.SenderId).Distinct() // <--
    .Select(key => new
    {
        Key = key,
        Documents = 
            context.Set<DbDocument>().Where(t => t.SenderId == key) // <--
                 .OrderByDescending(t => t.InsertedDateTime).Take(10)
                 .ToList() // <--
    });
```

If you need just flat result set containing top N items per key:

```
var query = context.Set<DbDocument>()
    .Where(t => partnerIds.Contains(t.SenderId))
    .Select(t => t.SenderId).Distinct() // <--
    .SelectMany(key => context.Set<DbDocument>().Where(t => t.SenderId == key) // <--
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.InsertedDateTime).Take(10)
    );
```

Comment: First query doesn't work when there are multiple key. It is always getting one key.

Comment: This helped me in so many ways that I cannot explain. When doing a GroupBy(x => x.key), translate it to Select(x => x.key).Distinct().SelectMany(key => <your_table>.Where(t => t.key == key).