# How to get n records of each group in mongodb using C#, LINQ?

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, linq

Need to get 10 items of each group. Order By Id decending and Group By Category

```
public class Item
{
  public string Id { get; set ; }
  public string Name { get ; set ; }
  public string Category { get ; set ; }
}
```

I tryied something like this.

```
    var data = Collection.AsQueryable()
              .OrderByDescending(o=> o.Id)
              .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
              .Select(g => new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = 
              g.Take(10).ToList() });
```

But got exception like this

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. at
> MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.AccumulatorBinder.GetAccumulatorArgument(Expression
> node)

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, what issues have you run into? We're not here to write the code for you.

Comment: What's wrong with the query you're using now? Does it not return 10 records from the groups?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.AccumulatorBinder.GetAccumulatorArgument(Expression node)

Comment: @KhairulAlam why are you doing this? `GroupName = g.Key, Items = 
              g.Take(10).ToList()` Can you explain

Comment: @vivek nuna, need 10 items for every category

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select top N rows for each group in a Entity Framework GroupBy with EF 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456026/how-to-select-top-n-rows-for-each-group-in-a-entity-framework-groupby-with-ef-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Aggregation Framework instead. MongoDB LINQ provider is built on top of it.

You can get 10 items of each group ordered by `Id` descending with the following query:

```
db.items.aggregate([
   { "$sort": { "Id": -1 } },
   { "$group": { "_id": "$Category", "Items": { "$push": "$$ROOT" } } },
   { "$project": { "_id": 0, "GroupName": "$_id", "Items": { "$slice": ["$Items", 10] } } }
])
```

C# code will be as follows:

```
// models
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsGroup
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

// query
var collection = db.GetCollection<Item>("Items");

IAggregateFluent<ItemsGroup> result = collection.Aggregate()
    .SortByDescending(o => o.Id)
    .Group(BsonDocument.Parse("{ _id: '$Category', Items: { '$push': '$$ROOT'}}"))
    .Project<ItemsGroup>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ _id: 0, GroupName: '$_id',  Items: { $slice: ['$Items', 10]}}"));

List<ItemsGroup> groups = result.ToList();
```

This query, however, may have a problem. If there are thousands of items for each group, I guess the group stage will keep them all in the `Items` temporary array, while we just want 10.

If the number of keys being grouped is not large then it would be better to do $lookup for each group instead of pushing everything into one array and then $slicing it. This can be achieved by the following query:

```
aggregate([
   { "$group": { "_id": "$Category" } },
   { "$lookup": { 
       "from": "Items",
       "let": { "c": "$_id" },
       "as": "Items"
       "pipeline": [
            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$Category", "$$c"] } } },
            { "$sort": { "Id": -1 } },
            { "$limit": 10 }
         ],        
      }
   },
   { "$project": { "_id": 0, "GroupName": "$_id", "Items": 1 } }
])
```

In C# code, it would be like:

```
BsonArray pipeline = new BsonArray
{
    BsonDocument.Parse("{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$Category', '$$c']} } }"),
    BsonDocument.Parse("{ $sort: { Id: -1 } }"),
    BsonDocument.Parse("{ $limit: 10 }")
};

BsonDocument lookup = new BsonDocument("$lookup",
    new BsonDocument("from", "Items")
        .Add("let", new BsonDocument("c", "$_id"))
        .Add("pipeline", pipeline)
        .Add("as", "Items")
);

IAggregateFluent<ItemsGroup> result = collection.Aggregate()
    .Group(BsonDocument.Parse("{ _id: '$Category' }"))
    .AppendStage<object>(lookup)
    .Project<ItemsGroup>("{ _id: 0, GroupName: '$_id', Items: 1 }");

List<ItemsGroup> groups = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @ruslan-gilmutdinov, it is working as expected...