# Retrieving the last record in each group with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do the retrieve the last record in each group like it does here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20770779/4789608

but in Entity Framework Core. Based on what's on the link, I can get the SQL to work to bring back the correct data using

```
select * 
from [Location] 
where [LocationModelId] in (select max([LocationModelId]) 
                            from [Location] 
                            group by [UserModelId])
```

or

```
select m1.* 
from [Location] m1 
left outer join [Location] m2 on (m1.[LocationModelId]< m2.[LocationModelId] 
                              and m1.[UserModelId] = m2.[UserModelId])
```

This is the closest I've gotten based on that link

```
locationDetails = _context.Location
    .GroupBy(p => p.UserModelId)
    .Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserModelId == p.Max(m => m.UserModelId)))
    .OrderBy(p => p.DateCreated)
    .ToList();
```

which returns this error message so, it's definitely not working.

> The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:\r\nKeySelector: l.UserModelId, \r\nElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: \r\n    EntityType: LocationModel\r\n    ValueBufferExpression: \r\n        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember\r\n    IsNullable: False\r\n\r\n    .FirstOrDefault(w => w.UserModelId == GroupByShaperExpression:\r\n    KeySelector: l.UserModelId, \r\n    ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: \r\n        EntityType: LocationModel\r\n        ValueBufferExpression: \r\n            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember\r\n        IsNullable: False\r\n\r\n        .Max(m => m.UserModelId))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: This would probably be supported in EFC 6.0. For EFC up to 5.0 use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59456026/how-to-select-top-n-rows-for-each-group-in-a-entity-framework-groupby-with-ef-3/59468439#59468439

Comment: You can do it with the help of some extension: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/)

Comment: I would used the pattern `.Where(r => r.value == r.Parent.Children.Max(c => c.value))`.

Answer (score 1):

This query should get you desired output. It is not fast as just SQL with window functions, but it should be acceptable.

```cs
var unique = _context.Location
    .Select(x => new {x.UserModelId})
    .Distinct();

var query =
    from u in unique
    from l in _context.Location
        .Where(x => x.UserModelId == u.UserModelId)
        .OrderByDescending(x.DateCreated)
        .Take(1)
    select l;

var locationDetails = query.ToList();
```